# What is the sum of this series: $\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}(1-p)^{k-2}\cdot p$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

I have:
$$\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}(1-p)^{k-2}\cdot p$$ $|p|<1$.
The sum is:
$$=\frac{(1-p)^{n-2}\cdot p}{1-(1-p)}=(1-p)^{n-2}$$ Or I wrong?
I use the fact that the sum of a series is: $\frac{a}{1-p}$ where $a$ is the first element and $|p|<1$.

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost. Just be careful of the condition on $p$. For example, if $p=-0.5$ then $1-p=1.5$ and the series diverges.

Comment: $0<p<1$ at our case....

Comment: The condition should be $|1-p|<1$, which is $0<p<2$.

Comment: It's from a probability question, so both $p$ and $1-p$ are at $[0,1]$... :-)